# GRE subject exam 0568 Q35.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, gre-exam

> At a banquet, $9$ women and $6$ men are to be seated in a row of $15$ chairs.
>
> If the entire seating arrangement is to be chosen at random, what is the probability that all of the men will be sated next to each other in $6$ consecutive positions?
>
> (A) $\dfrac1{{15}\choose{6}}$
>
> (B) $\dfrac{6!}{{15}\choose{6}}$
>
> (C) $\dfrac{10!}{15!}$
>
> (D) $\dfrac{6!10!}{15!}$
>
> (E) $\dfrac{6!10!}{15!}$

The correct answer is E, with the explanation as below:

> We will use the *Fundamental counting principle* extensively.
>
> First, the total number of permutations of men and women is $15!$.
>
> To find the number of permutations where all the men are seated next to each other, consider the collection of men to be one unit, which gives us $10!$ permutations of the women and the "men-unit".
>
> Within the "men-unit", there are $6!$ ways to seat the group of men. It follows that there are a total of $10!6!$ ways to seat the group if all the men sit together.
>
> Thus, the probability that all the men sit together is $\dfrac{10!6!}{15!}$

Could anyone explain for me why we divide by $15!$ in the answer?

Comment: Please type out your question, don't post a picture. Pictures take time to load, are not searchable on the site, and are not visible for some people on the site. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial for writing Maths nicely on the site, should you need it

Comment: @lioness99a  thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a probability $P$ is calculated as

$$P = \frac{\text{number of choices that count}}{\text{number of all choices}}$$

$15!$ is the total number of arrangements of $15$ people, so we have to divide by it.

Answer (score 1):

What is the size of sample space? Isn't it 15!?. Now use the classical definition of probability.